# Spring Integration file splitting sample doesn't react to content coming into inbound adapter channel

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, messaging, spring-integration-dsl

I'm testing out the following sample setup from [SI samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/main/applications/file-split-ftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/filesplit/Application.java) to understand and then adapt it to the similar set of tasks.  I won't need mailing functionality, but the rest of it seems adaptable enough to experiment.

**DailyCashReportApplication.java**

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:feeds-config.yml", factory = com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class DailyCashReportApplication  implements CommandLineRunner  {
    
    
    private final static String EMAIL_SUCCESS_SUFFIX = "emailSuccessSuffix";
    
    // sftp

    @Value("${sftp.in.host}")
    @Getter
    private String host;

    @Value("${sftp.in.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${sftp.in.user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${sftp.in.privateKey}")
    @Getter
    private String privateKeyLocation;

    @Value("${sftp.in.remoteDir}")
    @Getter
    private String remoteDir;


    @Value("${sftp.in.localDir}")
    @Getter
    private String localDir;

    @Value("${sftp.in.chmod}")
    private String chmod;

    @Value("${sftp.in.maxFetchSize}")
    @Getter
    private int maxFetchSize;



    @Value("${sftp.in.file.filter}")
    private String fileFilter;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    
//  @Autowired
//  @Qualifier("syntheticRunner") //TODO: to be replaced by runners consuming from appropriate data sources
//  private AbstractRunner runner; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("DailyCashReportApplication running...");
    
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(DailyCashReportApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //runner.run(args);
    }
```

**DcrConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class DcrConfig {

    private final static String EMAIL_SUCCESS_SUFFIX = "emailSuccessSuffix";
    
    // sftp

    @Value("${sftp.in.host}")
    @Getter
    private String host;

    @Value("${sftp.in.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${sftp.in.user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${sftp.in.privateKey}")
    @Getter
    private String privateKeyLocation;

    @Value("${sftp.in.remoteDir}")
    @Getter
    private String remoteDir;



    @Value("${sftp.in.localDir}")
    @Getter
    private String localDir;

    @Value("${sftp.in.chmod}")
    private String chmod;

    @Value("${sftp.in.maxFetchSize}")
    @Getter
    private int maxFetchSize;

//  @Value("${sftp.in.poller.fixedDelay}") @Getter
//  private int pollerFixedDelay;

    @Value("${sftp.in.file.filter}")
    private String fileFilter;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    
    @Bean(name = "downloadSftpSessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() throws IOException {

        Resource keyFileResource = resourceLoader.getResource(privateKeyLocation);

        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser(user);
        factory.setPrivateKey(keyFileResource);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }

    
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fromFile() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(remoteDir))
                                        .preventDuplicates(false)
                                        .patternFilter("*.txt"), 
                                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000).errorChannel("tfrErrors.input"))
                                        .id("fileInboundChannelAdapter"))
                .handle(Files.splitter(true, true))
                .<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, m->m
                        .channelMapping(FileSplitter.FileMarker.class, "markers.input")
                        .channelMapping(String.class, "lines.input"))
                .get();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FileWritingMessageHandlerSpec fileOut() {
        return Files.outboundAdapter(localDir)
                .appendNewLine(true)
                .fileNameExpression("payload.substring(1,4) + '.txt'");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow lines(FileWritingMessageHandler fileOut) {
        return f -> f.handle(fileOut); 
    }
    

    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow markers() throws IOException{
        return f -> f.<FileSplitter.FileMarker>filter(m -> m.getMark().equals(FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END),
                        e -> e.id("markerFilter"))
                .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s

                        // first trigger file flushes
                        .subscribe(sf -> sf.transform("'tmp/out/.*\\.txt'", e -> e.id("toTriggerPattern"))
                                .trigger("fileOut", e -> e.id("flusher")))

                        // send the first file
                        .subscribe(sf -> {
                            try {
                                sf.<FileSplitter.FileMarker, File>transform(p -> new File("tmp/out/002.txt"))
                                        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(FileHeaders.FILENAME, "002.txt", true))
                                        .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(ftp()).remoteDirectory("foo"), e -> e.id("ftp002"));
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        })

                        // send the second file
                        .subscribe(sf -> {
                            try {
                                sf.<FileSplitter.FileMarker, File>transform(p -> new File("/tmp/out/006.txt"))
                                        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(FileHeaders.FILENAME, "006.txt", true))
                                        .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(ftp()).remoteDirectory("foo"), e -> e.id("ftp006"));
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        })

                        // send the third file
                        .subscribe(sf -> {
                            try {
                                sf.<FileSplitter.FileMarker, File>transform(p -> new File("/tmp/out/009.txt"))
                                        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(FileHeaders.FILENAME, "009.txt", true))
                                        .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(ftp()).remoteDirectory("foo"), e -> e.id("ftp009"));
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        })


                        );
    }
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow tfrErrors() {
        return f -> f
//              .enrichHeaders(Mail.headers()
//                      .subject("File split and transfer failed")
//                      .from("foo@bar")
//                      .toFunction(m -> new String[] { "bar@baz"} ))
//              .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(EMAIL_SUCCESS_SUFFIX, ".failed")
//                  .headerExpression(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, "payload.failedMessage.headers['"
//                          + FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE + "']"))
//              .<MessagingException, String>transform(p->p.getFailedMessage().getPayload()+"\n"+getStackTraceAsString(p))
                .channel("toMail.input");
    }
    
    
    private String getStackTraceAsString(Throwable cause) {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter, true);
        cause.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
    }
    

    
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> ftp() throws IOException {

        Resource keyFileResource = resourceLoader.getResource(privateKeyLocation);

//      File keyFile = keyFileResource.getFile();
//      try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(keyFile))) {
//             String line;
//             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
//                 System.out.println(line);
//             }
//          }
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser(user);
        factory.setPrivateKey(keyFileResource);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MethodInterceptor afterMailAdvice() {
        return invocation -> {
            Message<?> message = (Message<?>) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
            File originalFile = headers.get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, File.class);
            try {
                invocation.proceed();
                originalFile.renameTo(new File(originalFile.getAbsolutePath() + headers.get(EMAIL_SUCCESS_SUFFIX)));
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                originalFile.renameTo(new File(originalFile.getAbsolutePath() + headers.get(EMAIL_SUCCESS_SUFFIX)+"email.failed"));
            }
            return null;
        };
    }
    
}
```

**application-dev.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: daily-cash-report-application

sftp:
  in:
    host: eafdev
    port: 22
    user: eafdev
    remoteDir: tmp/in 
    tmpDir: 
    localDir: tmp/out 
    maxFetchSize: 1    
    privateKey: file:///C:/Users/x12345/AppData/Roaming/SSH/UserKeys/distributessh
    chmod: 664 
    poller:
      fixedDelay: 10000
    file:
      filter: A.B.*    #TODO: calibrate once spec is known
  out:
    host: eafdev
    port: 22
    user: eafdev
    remoteDir: tmp/out  
    privateKey: file:///C:/Users/x12345/AppData/Roaming/SSH/UserKeys/distributessh
    chmod: 664 
  
file: 
  out:   
    targetDir: 
    tmpDir:
```

**DailyCashReportApplicationTest.java**

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = "fileInboundChannelAdapter")
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = { 
        DailyCashReportApplication.class,
        DcrConfig.class,
        })
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "application-dev.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@Slf4j
class DailyCashReportApplicationTest {

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void test()  {
        
        File in = new File("tmp/in/", "foo");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(in);
        fos.write("*002,foo,bar\n*006,baz,qux\n*009,fiz,buz\n".getBytes());
        fos.close();
        in.renameTo(new File("tmp/in/", "foo.txt"));
        
        File out = new File("tmp/out/002.txt");
        int n = 0;
        while (n++ < 100 && (!out.exists() || out.length() < 12)) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        assertThat(out.exists()).isTrue();
        
    }

}
```

The above test fails as it seems that the messages being put into `tmp/in` directory do not get picked up by the inbound file channel adapter and hence the `tmp/out` folder is empty.

What is missing?  Is there a way to *attach some logging* abilities to see what's going on in the messaging infrastructure more clearly?

Perhaps the following line in the test is the culprit that disables the needed behavior:

```
@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = "fileInboundChannelAdapter")
```

Not sure why it's there but commenting it out results in the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'tmp' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:223)
```

**Update**:
Looks like those ticks in the SpEL expresseion matter, changing to the following seems to make it send the files through the pipeline:

```
    @Bean
    public FileWritingMessageHandlerSpec fileOut() {
        return Files.outboundAdapter("'"+localDir+"'")
                .appendNewLine(true)
                .fileNameExpression("payload.substring(1,4) + '.txt'");
    }
```

Also, what's the *interpretation of the following expression* in the transformer:

```
"'tmp/out/.*\\.txt'"
```

Sounds like a wildcard for all text files in that specific directory but why does one need *all these extra dots and slashes* there?  Is it described in detail in some *documentation*?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Javadoc of that factory:

```
/**
 * Create a {@link FileWritingMessageHandlerSpec} builder for the one-way {@code FileWritingMessageHandler}.
 * @param directoryExpression the SpEL expression to evaluate target directory for writing files.
 * @return the {@link FileWritingMessageHandlerSpec} instance.
 */
public static FileWritingMessageHandlerSpec outboundAdapter(String directoryExpression) {
```

So, that argument is parsed as a SpEL expression, and since you rely on a literal for directory name, therefore it has to be quoted.

That part of code you are talking about:

```
                    // first trigger file flushes
                    .subscribe(sf -> sf.transform("'/tmp/out/.*\\.txt'", e -> e.id("toTriggerPattern"))
                            .trigger("fileOut", e -> e.id("flusher")))
```

is for a `MessageTriggerAction` implemented on the `FileWritingMessageHandler`. Also see `trigger()` and `FileWritingMessageHandler` Javadocs an docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/file/writing.html#file-flushing

Essentially we need that pattern from a transformer for the `DefaultFlushPredicate` in the `FileWritingMessageHandler`.

Comment: Thank you, Artem.  How does one interpret the `.*\\\` part of the SpEL expression?  Why is the test configured with `@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = "fileInboundChannelAdapter")` enabled in the first place?  How does one add more logging into the pipeline?

Comment: This is not SpEL expression. That transformer returns a plain string which is a regexp for a trigger action. See `DefaultFlushPredicate` source code.